# How to delete the cluster datanode in unknown state in Apache IoTDB?

Tags: database, apache-iotdb, iotdb

Can the datanode in the unknown state be deleted from the cluster in Apache IoTDB? Now, I killed the datanode process first, but then I cannot start this datanode. When starting, the system reported that this DataNode conflicts with other registered datanodes. I also tried to use the `remove-datanode.sh` command to remove this datanode, but I cannot connect to this datanode, so it also failed. Anyone know how can I delete this datanode in this case?

Answer (score 0):

The datanode in `unknown` status in Apache IoTDB can be deleted using the `remove` command you mentioned. Usually the error you encountered is because the ongoing datanode process has not been thoroughly killed. You can try to restart both confignode and datanode and try to execute the command again.